# Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP & comparing with Javascript Date.now()

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, time, unix-timestamp

I have a question regarding Timestamp & epoch time.

Let's say I have a MySQL server that actually has their timezone set to *00:00* (that is GMT) and has a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
`mid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`username` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`mid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

in which you store messages. I also have a JS file which compares the last message from that table and compares it with Client's time. I have logged them in console.log and here's my question. Shouldn't the last message's timestamp always be less than client unix timestamp?

I'm getting these results:

```
Last message: 1509580533
My timestamp: 1509570014.969
~~~
Last message: 1509580533
My timestamp: 1509570016.179
~~~
Last message: 1509580533
My timestamp: 1509570016.729
```

Here's my code:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse("2017-11-01 20:55:33")/1000; //for example
console.log("Last message: " + timestamp);
console.log("My timestamp:" + Date.now() / 1000);
```

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: `Date.now()` returns local time

Comment: @SuperStormer Yeah I know, and that's my objective. I always get my current timestamp (Date.now()) to be less than server's message timestamp (even if the message was stored for example yesterday). In theory Date.now()'s should always return a timestamp greater than any past timestamps.

Comment: @SuperStormer—no it doesn't. It returns the [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-constructor-date), which is UTC.

Comment: Your last message time value must be incorrect, 1509580533000 is about half an hour from now, so in the future. Also, `Date.parse("2017-11-01 20:55:33")` is error prone (in Safari it returns NaN), see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)